# How to get a list of shared Calendars in Microsoft graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Is it possible to get a list of users (or user ids) who shared their calendars with the person logged in?

I want to have a list of calendars where I can call as I do with

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user shared the calendar')/calendars
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a way you can take it one step closer to what you want using the beta endpoint: do a `GET /calendars` for the signed-in user, and for each calendar, check the `isSharedWithMe` property. If that property is true, the **owner** property would show the display name and SMTP address of the user who shared the calendar.

Other than the user ID, you can use the SMTP address to index into the `users` collection in a tenant as well.

You can see a description of the `calendar` properties in the [Graph documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-beta#properties).

Please be aware that `isSharedWithMe`, and in general, APIs in the beta endpoint, are subject to change without notice. For that reason, production apps should not take a dependency on such APIs.